# Can we hightlight one particular node in a subject tree - crm 2011

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I wanted to know is it possible to highlight a particular node in subject tree as shown in image below. Whenever user opens lookup, one particular node should be highlighted by default. This is to help user in selecting correct subject tree node always. 
In the below screen shot Default Subject is highlighted. I want subject tree look like this whenever user opens lookup without selecting any node.
[image: Subject Tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that list is just sorted alphabetically - there’s nothing special about the 'Default' subject, that’s just the name that has been given to it.

So you could just prefix with something to make it appear at the top of the list, then I think it should be selected by default.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply James, i don't want to change the name of subject instead one particular subject should be highlighted when user opens the lookup. When subject tree contains more than one subjects then based on the lead type particular subject should be highlighted. Is it possible ?.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible (at least in a sensible supported way). The highlighted record is simply the first one in the list, so if you change the name, it will appear at the top of the list and be highlighted. E.g. '* Locus IT...'.